# i18n-tasks command error on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n, i18n-tasks

I'm building a new Rails application that's using the [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) gem, but when I run the command `i18n-tasks` this output is shown:

```
/home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/gems/i18n-tasks-0.5.1/lib/i18n/tasks/plural_keys.rb:3:in `<module:PluralKeys>': uninitialized constant I18n::Tasks::PluralKeys::Set (NameError)
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/gems/i18n-tasks-0.5.1/lib/i18n/tasks/plural_keys.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/gems/i18n-tasks-0.5.1/lib/i18n/tasks/base_task.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/gems/i18n-tasks-0.5.1/lib/i18n/tasks.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/gems/i18n-tasks-0.5.1/bin/i18n-tasks:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/bin/i18n-tasks:23:in `load'
    from /home/user-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@product/bin/i18n-tasks:23:in `<main>'
```

What's the main problem? Why can't I run these commands as in [README](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/blob/v0.5.1/README.md) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was with how to run the `i18n-tasks` command. The [Readme](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/blob/master/README.md) file says that I can execute:

```
i18n-tasks
```

But the command executed directly fails for me. To work properly, the command needs to run as:

```
bundle exec i18n-tasks
```

This was all.

Comment: I find that when the __i18n gem__ is installed through bundler by defining it in the `Gemfile`, then I need to run `bundle exec i18n-tasks` for any task. If I want to run `i18n-tasks` directly then I have to also install the gem from the command line, `gem install i18n-tasks`. Now I can use it directly without going through `bundler exec`.